# Which are the files created while installing a package..suppose httpd?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, apache-2.4, fedora

I know /etc/http and /var/www/html folder will be created.Also init.d file and log files for service will be created.Other than this what are the changes occuring?Could anyone explain this please.

I have one more doubt.On uninstalling apache2 wheather library function is removed automatically?

Comment: That depends on the distribution. You can inspect the packages to see what files and scripts they contain.

Comment: @Schneider..Thnaks for the reply.

Answer (score 2):

You can see which files directories are installed by and belong to a package from the package manager.

You will also need to check the scripts that the package manager executes when it installs or removes a package, as in addition to other actions those are sometimes also used by the package maintainer to create/remove files and directories.

For RPM based distributions such as Red Hat Enterprise Linux, CentOS and Fedora:

```
rpm -ql httpd 

  /etc/httpd
  /etc/httpd/conf
  /etc/httpd/conf.d
  /etc/httpd/conf.d/README
  ...
  /var/www
  /var/www/cgi-bin
  /var/www/html
```

Or the reverse, query which package a file belongs to:

```
rpm -qf /etc/httpd

   httpd-2.4.6-67.el7.centos.6.x86_64
```

And to query the package scripts:

```
rpm -q --scripts httpd

preinstall scriptlet (using /bin/sh):
# Add the "apache" group and user
/usr/sbin/groupadd -g 48 -r apache 2> /dev/null || :
/usr/sbin/useradd -c "Apache" -u 48 -g apache \
    -s /sbin/nologin -r -d /usr/share/httpd apache 2> /dev/null || :
postinstall scriptlet (using /bin/sh):
...
```

And I imagine for Ubuntu `dpkg` or the other .deb package mangement tools offer similar functionality.

Comment: @HBruijn..thanks for the replay..Iam using an ubuntu system and i have checked it by dpkg-query -L apache2 in ubuntu.Its working fine.I want to know what will happen to library functions when i uninstall a package.Wheather it gets removed automatically.

Comment: ServerFault is Q&A platform and combining multiple questions in a single question (or asking them in comments) doesn't work too well. Also I simply don't know ;)